# How to Substract using Posgres within same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I need to subtract the raw data using same column. 
The formula is 
(provisioned port-shelf x 16 ) - (provisioned summary - provisioned RCMM).

[image]

Anyone have idea so that i can improve my query.

Comment: Given your sample data, shouldn't your expected results be `((2 * 16) -13-3 = 16)`?

Comment: it is (2*16) - (13-3) = 32 - 10 = 22

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Forgive me as i loaded an image of raw data to ask question. I try to write it but i don't know the setting became not correctly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, given your sample data, your expected result should be 16 for A.  Assuming so, here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select ne,
       max(case when type = 'port-shelf' then 16 * provisioned else 0 end) -
       max(case when type = 'summary' then provisioned else 0 end) - 
       max(case when type = 'rcmm' then provisioned else 0 end) as free_slot,
       insert_date
from yourtable
group by ne, insert_date
```

Comment: Thank you sgeddes. It works !! I just edit to match the formula.